# Initialize array of key-value tuples of which the value has a generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I need an array of key-value tuples of which the value has a generic type. I do not want to declare value as System.Object. Desired usage would be like this:

```
Pair[] pairs = new Pair[]
{
  new Pair<int> { Name = "Age", Value = 44 },
  new Pair<string> { Name = "FirstName", Value = "Frank" },
};
```

With `Pair` defined like this:

```
public class Pair<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

This gives the following compile error when declaring and initializing `pairs`:

> Using the generic type 'Pair<T>' requires 1 type arguments

If I would change the code like this:

```
Pair<int>[] pairs = new Pair<int>[]
{
   new Pair<int> { Name = "Age", Value = 44 },
   new Pair<string> { Name = "FirstName", Value = "Frank" },
};
```

It would obviously satisfy the `Pair<int>` but not the `Pair<string>`:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Pair<string>' to 'Pair<int>'

If I would change the code like this:

```
Pair<object>[] pairs = new Pair<object>[]
{
    new Pair<int> { Name = "Age", Value = 44 },
    new Pair<string> { Name = "FirstName", Value = "Frank" },
};
```

Then the compile error is (twice):

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Pair<int>' to 'Pair<object>'

--- update

The reason that I do not want to declare Pair.Value as object is that I want to define special pairs as follows:

```
public class AgePair : Pair<int> { }

public class NamePair : Pair<string> { }
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Well, there are the interfaces: `Pair<IComparable>` and `Pair<IConvertible>`. Pretty obscure though.

Comment: Can you give examples of what you would then want to do with this Pair array? It doesn't look like you are going to be able to do anything useful with it if the type of value can be anything because you won't know when writing code that uses this array what the type is so the code you write could only refer to it as an object...

Comment: As been stated you cant do this with generics out of the box,. however it depends how far you want to go down this rabbit hole, how many types are we talking , how many key strokes do you want to save, there is a weird and wonderful world of lists classes and extension methods you could write

Comment: See my update. The classes are part of a public API that model PDF tag attributes.

Comment: you could use `obejct[]` instead of `Pair[]`. Afterwards you would have to check each pair for it's type...

Comment: There´s no way to have an array of types determined at *runtime* and expect the *compiler* to know those types. The compiler doesn´t know *anything* about the objects you actually put into that array *at runtime*.

Comment: @Mat I am aiming for a static solution.

Answer (score 1):

Although `Pair<int>` and `Pair<string>` share the classdefinition of `Pair<T>`, they are compiled to entirely different types at runtime. Thatfor, you cannot put them in an `IEnumerable<T>` or `T[]` Type. You simply cannot do that (directly).

If you let your Class `Pair<T>` inherit from a class `Pair` which returns the Value object as Type object, you can use a `IEnumerable<Pair>` or `Pair[]` and upon use of the object check the `typeof(Value)` respectively.

This is very unclean though and changes the implementation of the result based on its type instead of it‘s definition which would violate OOP principles and adds hidden complexity. This is exactly the reason why Key-Value storage is usually done as string-string or string-object with object being of a type that‘s defined in a complex (multiple Properties and Methods) class.